# Why isn't `bash -c` working in this desktop/launcher?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, command-line, launcher

I have a `.desktop` file to start [Youtube-Viewer](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/youtube-viewer-complete-youtube-client.html) which is an application that runs in terminal.

The command to use is something like `youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer`.

It works when I fire that in a terminal, but I want to add it in a `.desktop` file (and put that in `usr/share/applications` or `~/.share/applications`). In Linux Mint, which I use in parallel, a such desktop file works:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Youtube-viewer
Exec=bash -c 'youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer'
Icon=youtube-viewer
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;Player;Recorder;
```

But that does not work as it should in elementary OS, it just does nothing.

What am I missing here?

---

**UPDATE**

I don't know why the line `Exec=bash -c 'youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer'` isn't working, but what works is `Exec=pantheon-terminal -e 'youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer'`.

---

**UPDATE2**

A script like

```
#!/bin/bash

bash -c 'youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer'
```

doesn't work.

But this works:

```
#!/bin/bash

pantheon-terminal -e 'youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer'
```

Comment: please comment your (down)vote

Answer (score 1):

Both options work for me.

Have you checked whether you can run the first option `bash -c 'youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer'` on a Terminal?

Comment: that command works in terminal. But `bash -c` is not needed there, as the idea is just to run `youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer` in terminal. I just checked again tough and that desktop file doesn't work, until I replace `bash -c` with `pantheon-terminal -e`

Comment: My idea was that something might be wrong with bash, that's why I asked if you can run the bash command.

Comment: see UPDATE2 please

Comment: Both options work for me.

Have you tried removing that part altogether and write `Exec=youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer`?

Comment: yes, but that couldn't work, because that application has no window and needs the terminal window to run. What works is `Exec=path/to/script-working-in-UPDATE2` but that is the same as `Exec=pantheon-terminal -e 'youtube-viewer --video-player=mplayer'`